# Проблема с wi-fi Linux Mint

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-mint

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с проблемой на Linux Mint, при подключению к wi-fi все полностью зависает, спасает только принудительная перезагрузка.

Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter

Находил такую же проблему для Ralink corp. RT3290, которая решалась переустановкой драйверов, мне же это не помогло. При чем lan соединение работает прекрасно, как и всё остальное.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пробуйте последнее ядро из доступных вначале.